# How to delete file after upload using node?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using multiparty to upload some file on the server, I have notice that when using `form.parse` a file is being added in temp in SO file system.

I need to remove that file after form close but I cannot get information of file path.

Any idea how to solve this problem?

```
function onUpload(req, res) {
  var form = new multiparty.Form();

  form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
    onSimpleUpload(fields, files[fileInputName][0], res);
  });

  // Close emitted after form parsed
  form.on('close', function() {
    // cannot get file here to be deleted
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be specific:

```
var fs = require('fs');

var filePath = files[fileInputName][0].path;
fs.unlinkSync(filePath);
```

or async:

```
var fs = require('fs');

var filePath = files[fileInputName][0].path;
fs.unlink(filePath, function(err){
  if(err) // do something with error
  else // delete successful
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the path of file saved on local filesystem, by `files[fileInputName][0].path`